# Plugged an NTFS drive into a Mac and ruined the partition table/MBR?

Tags: mac, partitioning, ntfs, mbr

I recently plugged an NTFS hard drive which I believed to be functional into a Mac Mini via a SATA-to-USB adapter. The Mac did not appear to read the drive, and after waiting a while and giving up, I unplugged the drive, which caused several error messages to be displayed. Obviously, this means the Mac did read the drive, but for a mystery reason was unable to display its contents or show the drive in Finder's sidebar. Now, when the drive is reinserted, I am prompted to initialize the drive.

When it's plugged into a PC running Windows 7, the drive is only recognized by Drive Management as an unrecognized format. Windows prompts me to repair the MBR or Partition Table.

I need to recover this drive without deleting data. Windows Recovery Console does not recognize the drive, so I'm unable to use the `fixmbr` command. What options do I have? Will the built-in Windows MBR/partition table erase data from the drive in the process?

Comment: Your Mac didn't touch the partition, unless you have the NTFS driver installed (which isn't installed by default). You probably have a dead drive, and using a third-party data recovery tool is your best bet now.

Comment: The Mac I was using had both MacFUSE and TuxeraNTFS apparently installed.

Comment: M. West makes a very good point, regardless.  You need to determine whether your disc unit is actually faulty, or whether it is operating properly and it is simply the case that the partition/volume metadata on it have been overwritten/wiped.  You need to use _read-only tools_ to start from the basics and work upwards.  Tell us what Device Manager says about the device.  Show us the output of `diskpart`'s `list partition` command.

Comment: When the drive is plugged in, Disk Management detects it as "Disk 2", but the type is "Unknown", and it states that I `must initialize a disk before Logical Disk Manager can access it.` It gives me the option of initializing it using the MBR or GPT partition styles.

`diskpart` does not detect the drive at all, after a `rescan`, after for example Disk Management can see that there is an unknown device connected.

This is on a Windows 7 PC. (thank you all for your help!)